# setContentView by using extending view class

Tags: android

I am using extends View for setting content of an activity..what is happening it is showing blank activity.instead of setting text.

```
public class ThreadCheck extends Activity{
        MyView view;
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
            view=new MyView(ctx);
            setContentView(view);
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class MyView extends View{
            TextView tvThread;
            public MyView(Context context) {
                super(context);
                tvThread=new TextView(context);
                tvThread.setText("Hello This Is Myview");
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
view=new MyView(ctx);
```

to

```
view=new MyView(ThreadCheck.this);
```

And change to

```
   public class MyView extends TextView{

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setText("Hello This Is Myview");
    }

}
```

Edit: to the question in comment. You need a ViewGroup to which you add your views.

```
public class MyView extends RelativeLayout{

        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);


            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            TextView tv = new TextView(context);
            tv.setText("hello");
            tv.setId(1);

            Button b = new Button(context);
            params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv.getId());
            b.setText("Hi");
            b.setId(2);

            this.addView(tv);
            this.addView(b, params1);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could just use `addView(view)` to add your custom view to the existing layout.

Comment: Thanks it slove half of my prob..What i am looking for is to have a class for setting layout of activity instead of using R.layout.xml .In that class i can have button textview etc..this particular solution only add textview...what my thinking is have a view than add in it differnt thing like button ,text ,edit...i don't know i am  doing it right.

Comment: @PraveenPandey you need to have a custom view for that. that is a different question. pls ask a new question. One question per post pls. Read a book Professional Android Development by Reto Meier.

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks ..i am new to stack overflow.will ask in new post.

Comment: @PraveenPandey you need custom view group not custom view.