# Programmed Android app Does not Show in an AVD

Tags: java, android, sdk

So I've been trying to learn from this book, and I did exactly what it said (at least I think so), but the app does not show in the AVD.
I have 2 classes in my package named `(com.example.crazyeights)`:
`CrazyEightsActivity.java` & `CrazyEightsView.java`
under `CrazyEightsActivity`, I have:

```
package com.example.crazyeights;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class CrazyEightsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CrazyEightsView CrazyEightsView = new CrazyEightsView(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And under `CrazyEightsView.java` I have:

```
package com.example.crazyeights;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class CrazyEightsView extends View
{
    private Paint redPaint;
    private int circleX;
    private int circleY;
    private float radius;

public CrazyEightsView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        redPaint = new Paint();
        redPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        redPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        circleX = 100;
        circleY = 100;
        radius = 30;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawCircle(circleX, circleY, radius, redPaint);
    }

}
```

I've already made a "test-app" just to see if it works with my AVD, which it does.
Thanks for the help!

EDIT: My `AndroidManifest.xml` currently looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.crazyeights"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.crazyeights.CrazyEightsActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you also have the manifest file?

If you have a manifest did you add the new activity to the manifest like this:

```
    <activity>
        android:name="com.example.crazyeights.CrazyEightsActivity"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I copied and replaced it with the <activity.... </activity> part in androidManifest.xml However, I get an error:                     Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Comment: Put > after ...CrazyEightsActivity"

Comment: Hmm... Did I do this right? (I edited my original post with my .xml)

Answer (score 0):

You Have to some changes in CrazyEightsActivity  this class

1)OnCreateMethod

```
   @Override     
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
         setContentView(new CrazyEightsView(CrazyEightsActivity.this));
}
```

Comment: "You Have to some changes in CrazyEightsActivity this class" What does this mean?

Comment: your custom view class name is CrazyEightsView ok then you have to show this view  using setcontentview(id)

CrazyEightsView crazyEightView=new CrazyEightsView(CrazyEightsActivity.this);

setContentView(crazyEightView);

//if you have to reference the example i m passing the //stackoverflow link
//check this link for reference
**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513478/setcontentview-by-using-extending-view-class**